# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object in Azure Rest API RoleDefinition Object Body - PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-rest-api

I'm creating an [RoleDefinition Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/createorupdate) Function and run into an JSON Format issue for the [Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roledefinitions/createorupdate#request-body).

This is how I try to create the JSON-Body:

```
$requestBody = [PSCustomObject]@{
    properties = @{
        assignableScopes = $RoleDefinition.properties.assignableScopes
        description      = $RoleDefinition.properties.description
        permissions      = @{
            actions    = $RoleDefinition.properties.permissions.actions
            notActions = $RoleDefinition.properties.permissions.notActions 
        }
        roleName         = $RoleDefinition.properties.roleName
        type             = $RoleDefinition.properties.type
    }
}
$body = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $requestBody -Depth 3
```

The JSON/ Result looks pretty well but I get a "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object" Error. Especially for the 'properties.permissions.actions' object.

```
{
    "properties":  {
                       "assignableScopes":  [
                                                "Foo",
                                                "Bar",
                                                "Baz"
                                            ],
                       "description":  "My Role Description",
                       "roleName":  "May Role Name",
                       "type":  "CustomRole",
                       "permissions":  {
                                           "actions":  [
                                                            "Foo",
                                                            "Bar",
                                                            "Baz"
                                                       ],
                                           "notActions":  [
                                                            "Foo",
                                                            "Bar",
                                                            "Baz"
                                                          ]
                                       }
                   }
}
```

In case I forgot something, I've added the entire error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The content of your request was not valid, and the original object could not be deserialized. Exception message:        
'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'Microsoft.Authorization.PASFE.Models.PASRP.AzurePermission[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g.   
[1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a      
primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to         
deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'properties.permissions.actions', line 10, position 53.'"}}
At C:\Users\Foo\localGit\custom_roles\scripts\Test2.ps1:82 char:20
+ ...  $Respond = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $ApiUri -Headers $Toke ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Your code does not return array properties for me. Try to declare array implicitly where that needs. Like  `properties = [Array]@{`

Comment: Not really sure, but I think `permissions` should also be an array: `permissions = @( @{ actions = @($RoleDefinition.properties.permissions.actions); notActions = @($RoleDefinition.properties.permissions.notActions) } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Theo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608314/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-in-azure-rest-api-roledefinition-obje?noredirect=1#comment117754911_66608314) replay made the difference! Thanks to both!

```
$requestBody = [PSCustomObject]@{
    properties = @{
        assignableScopes = $RoleDefinition.properties.assignableScopes
        description      = $RoleDefinition.properties.description
        permissions      = @( 
            @{ 
                actions    = @($RoleDefinition.properties.permissions.actions); 
                notActions = @($RoleDefinition.properties.permissions.notActions) 
            } 
        )
        roleName         = $RoleDefinition.properties.roleName
        type             = $RoleDefinition.properties.type
    }
}
$body = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $requestBody -Depth 4
```